# Появление модального окна с задержкой и без перехода по ссылке.

Tags: jquery

Вопрос такой: 
У меня есть ссылка, по клику на которую появляется модальное окно. Сделал запрет перехода по ссылке, модальное окно появилось, но мне нужно чтобы после показа модального окна по таймеру произошел переход по указанной ссылке. Как это можно сделать?

```
    setTimeout(function () {
    $('.basket').on("click", function(){
        $("#delivery-conditions").modal('show');
        return false
    });
    return true
},1000);
```

Comment: Что именно не понятно: как таймер поставить или как по ссылке переход осуществить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `javascript` редирект делают методом `window.location.href`.

Вот как можно сделать у вас:

```html
<div id="delivery-conditions" style="display: none;">modalll</div>
<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/" class="basket">click me</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.basket').on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#delivery-conditions").show('slow');
        var this_href = $(this).attr('href');
        setTimeout(function(){
          window.location.href = this_href;
        }, 2000);
        
    });
</script>
```